# View is not stretching properly in Open Laszlo 4.9

Tags: migration, openlaszlo, lzx

i created one view which will scale the views inside that particular view. The code is working properly in OL 3.3 but its not working inOL 4.9

Comment: Do you see the behavior in both runtimes, or only in DHTML?

Comment: @RajuBitter: I am able to see this in swf 10 and in dhtml runtime.

Comment: @RajuBitter, saw that canvas.width on init of scaling view is printing as 500 in OL 3.3 where as it's printing as 1256 in OL 4.9

Comment: OL 3.3 had a default value of 500 for canvas. If the browser window is larger, the value should be updated at a later initialization stage. If that doesn't happen, does the value in 3.3 change when you resize the browser window?

Comment: @RajuBitter: Yes the value of the width changes after sometime to the original. But still i dont understand why the view is not getting stretched. I gave both the values one before initialization and one after initialization. And in both the cases the view is still not stretched.

Comment: When I ported from 3.3.3 SWF8 to 4.7.0 SWF8 I encountered many problems like this. When I later ported to SWF9/10 the problems no longer showed up unless I compiled to the SWF8 run-time, so I think there are bugs in the SWF8 run-time of 4.9.0 in regards to stretching nested views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way scaling of views works has been changed, first [with the 4.0 release](http://wiki.openlaszlo.org/Runtime_Differences#Stretching_nested_subviews) (since back then browsers didn't support scaling of nested divs). For OpenLaszlo 4.9 an xscale and yscale property were added to views. Check the corresponding JIRA for the detais: http://jira.openlaszlo.org/jira/browse/LPP-9865

Here is a simple example, it works for me in both runtimes for OpenLaszlo 5.0:

```
<canvas>

    <class name="testbox" width="120" height="120" bgcolor="blue">
        <text text="${'xscale=' + parent.xscale + ' / yscale=' + parent.yscale}" fgcolor="white"/>
        <view x="30" y="30" width="60" height="60" bgcolor="red"></view>
    </class>


    <testbox x="20" y="50" />

    <testbox x="20" y="200" xscale="2"/>

    <testbox x="20" y="350" yscale="1.5"/>

</canvas>
```

Here is a screenshot of how the app running using the DHTML runtime 5.0:
[image: OpenLaszlo 4.9+ xscale and yscale attributes used for stretching views]

Comment: Ok thank you. I 'll use this approach and see whether this is solving my approach or not.

Comment: In the SWF10 runtime, the clipping of the text elements looks broken with my example, for xscale!=1. Probably a bug in the OpenLaszlo text kernel.